# Valgrind Memcheck for PostgreSQL C function

Tags: c, postgresql, shared-libraries, valgrind

I wrote a C Language Function for PostgreSQL. It imports data from OpenStreetMap into my own database but it seems I have a memory leak somewhere. I tried to check it with valgrind:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/some/path/libohdm-import.so' valgrind --leak-check=full psql ohdm-dev -c "select ohdmImport('somefile.osm');"
```

but every time I get the following error:

```
valgrind: symbol lookup error: /some/path/libohdm-import.so: undefined symbol: SPI_processed
```

I imported the header files from postgres correctly. The function successfully finishes with smaller map data like Fiji Islands but with bigger ones I get a Out-of-Memory.

My question is: How do I get valgrind to run with this?

Comment: Are you using palloc() (in line#42) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error aside, this simply won't work. You're running `valgrind` on the `psql` *client application*, but expecting it to check for memory errors on the *server backend*. Your code isn't loaded into `psql` and `valgrind` can't check it there. Kind of like starting a debugger on `chrome` when you're tracing a crash in `apache`....

You will need to start the PostgreSQL server under valgrind. You should use the valgrind suppressions file supplied by PostgreSQL in `src/tools/valgrind.supp`, e.g. `--suppressions=/path/to/postgresql/sources/src/tools/valgrind.supp`.

You cannot attach valgrind memcheck to an existing process, because it needs to keep track of the process state from startup. Since PostgreSQL backends `fork()` from the postmaster, valgrind has to keep track of everything since postmaster start. You have to trace the whole database server.

See the [PostgreSQL wiki on valgrind](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Valgrind). In particular, note the compile options that'll help give better valgrind results.

By the way, PostgreSQL uses heirachical memory contexts, which you access with `palloc`, `pfree`, `MemoryContextAlloc`, `SetMemoryContext` etc. You should only `malloc` memory if you're going to pass it to another library that will `free` it, or you are `free`ing memory `malloc`d by a library you're using. For PostgreSQL backend code use the PostgreSQL allocators so that memory is automatically cleaned up if an exception terminates the function, etc.

Comment: I forgot ... (my) postgresql is on 9.1.18 not 9.4 so I don't have the valgrind.supp in the sources
And I can't upgrade because I'm not the server admin

I'm using palloc and pfree

Comment: ok ... found the memory leak ... used 2 functions from an xml reader lib that allocates memory .... but still thanks for your help and I'll keep what you wrote in mind